# How can i make my own command to my first console application in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, console, console-application

I'm doing my first VB.NET console application. I have some experience making VB.NET "non-console" applications.

My guestion is, how can i make my own commands to my console application. For example if user types to console "Hello World" and then the application would answer back to the user. I dont want it to be like "Press any key to continue..." nothing like that. I just want to make my own commands.

I've already tried to find some help from YouTube or Google but i couldn't find anything that would help even little. So i'm asking from you guys.

I also would like an answer soon as possible.

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+can+i+make+my+own+commands+to+my+console+application) would be a great start, there are tuts out there as well as plenty of information on this. Please show us what you have tried and what isn't working so we can better assist you.

Comment: Do you know how to compile a program to an EXE?

Comment: I have done the seach for you (in a few seconds). Search link: https://www.google.com/search?q=vb.net+console+input+parameters&oq=VB.NET+console+input&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.20582j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 7 Example link: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/880476/Vb-net-Console-Application-Parsing-Command-Line-Pa

Answer (score 1):

`Console.ReadLine` will block execution until the user has pressed the enter key.  It then returns the full string of whatever the user typed on that line.  You can then write conditional code which acts on whatever that returns.  So, for instance:

```
Dim input As String = Console.ReadLine()
If input = "Hello World" Then
    Console.WriteLine("Hello to you too")
End If
```